# How do i keep UISwitch state when changing ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, state, uiswitch

When I move from one view controller to another, the switch on the first controller resets itself and does not retain its state. 
How can I make it save its state when  come back to it after viewing other controllers? And how do I make it save its state after closing the app. I have looked at the various stackOverflow questions and responses and the apple documentation, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my class for the View Controller that has the switch.

```
class Days: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var switchButton: UISwitch!
    var switchState = true
    let switchKey = "switchState"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    @IBAction func saveSwitchPressed(sender:AnyObject) {
        if self.switchButton.on {
            self.switchState = true
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(self.switchState, forKey: switchKey)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(switchKey))
        } else {
            self.switchState = false
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(self.switchState, forKey: switchKey)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(switchKey))
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a beginner to Swift and generally Xcode. Thank you in advance for your time and help :)

Comment: You've saved the state into NSUserDefaults but on your view load, did you fetch the value from NSUserDefaults and update the toggle switch based on that value ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to save its state at all if you're returning to the same instance. Are you coming back to the same instance (how are you coming back)? You shouldn't use NSUserDefaults for this purpose unless you need the data to persist between launches of your app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Xcode 8.3 • Swift 3.1**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var switchButton: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        switchButton.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
    }

    @IBAction func saveSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW You have to name your classes starting with an UpperCaseLetter

Comment: I forgot to mention the IBAction is connected to the Sent Events: Value Changed

Comment: Thanks for your time, but now i get an error when i view the controller in the debug area: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You should check if the outlets and the buttons are connected because boolForKey never returns nil. It only returns true or false

Comment: Can I add you on facebook so we can discuss this?

Comment: As @leoDabus said I was receiving the same error and could not figure it out.  But I read his answer and realized I had not hooked up the switch on the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're syncing the on/off state of the switch you could on `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` set the state of the switch to the value stored in `NSUserDefaults`

Something along the lines of

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  self.switchButton.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(switchKey)
}
```

Comment: Do i add these lines of code or do i replace it with the viewDidLoad method?

Answer (score 0):

*just after code connect UISwitch to IBoutlet.*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var switchButton: UISwitch!

    @objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender:UISwitch!)
    {
        if (sender?.isOn == true){
            print("on")
        }
        else {
            print("off")
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(false)
        switchButton?.isOn =  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
        switchButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchStateDidChange(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```