# Setting and Saving UISwitch Value Error

Tags: swift, xcode, uiswitch

My problem is that the UISwitch I have in my settings page keeps reverting to an off state once you leave the settings page meaning there is no way of using the switch properly. I did some searching around and found this question and answer: 
[How do i keep UISwitch state when changing ViewControllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28555255/how-do-i-keep-uiswitch-state-when-changing-viewcontrollers)

I read this page and added the answer to my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var NumSwitch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NumSwitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBAction func SaveSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
}
```

However when I run this code I get:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

(Highlighting the line: 'NumSwitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")')

[I am using Xcode 8.2.1]

I have connected two UIViewControllers to one ViewController Class so maybe that is causing the problem. I have tried many many other methods to make my switch work properly and this one seems to have worked for other people. Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

[I would have liked to have added this as a comment on the aforementioned question but I do not have the reputation to do so]

Comment: check `NumSwitch` is nil ?

Comment: Hello @Mike Alter, How exactly should I do that? I am rather new to swift and xcode

Comment: verify to `print(NumSwitch)` is not `nil`

Comment: so I should create a UI label?

Comment: No, Check your `NumSwitch ` is not `nil`

Comment: I am working with the UI so how should I check this, with an if statment or some other method?

Comment: What I am trying to say is I'm not sure how to print(NumSwitch) when not working in the swift playground

Comment: Copy and paste it: `override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
print(NumSwitch)    
NumSwitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
}`

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer. I used the `print(NumSwitch)` but it gave me the `Thread 1:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)` is this a sign of `NumSwitch` being nil?

Comment: Yes it is nil ,I don't understand why you assign same class to two viewcontrollers ?

Comment: You have to reconnect the outlet if it indicates with the same class.

Comment: To answer your question @MikeAlter I am not very good with xcode and I did not know any other way to get two viewcontrollers to communicate

Comment: I have looked at all the outlets and none seem to be problematic (and I have reconnected them multiple times in the past) though Ill try it again

Comment: I reconnected `@IBOutlet weak var NumSwitch: UISwitch!` then ran the program but still got an error

Comment: *"I am not very good with xcode and I did not know any other way to get two viewcontrollers to communicate"* This may be the root of your problem. *"I am working with the UI"* Is this indicating that you are using IB (Interface Builder) and a storyboard? Either way, look into segues - they are fairly straightforward and will make it pretty easy to pass variables between two view controllers, including a switch state.

Comment: I am using ViewController.swift programing and the Main.storyboard for the UI. Thanks for the tip about segues I didn't know they existed until today and I have been using more view controllers for the other parts of my app.

Comment: What is your viewcontrollers view hierarchy? Are you putting the switch inside a view?

Comment: The hierarchy goes: `View Controller Scene: View Controller: View: NumSwitch`

Answer (score -1):

If everything is hooked up to your outlets correctly then the following should work:

```
@IBOutlet weak var NumSwitch: UISwitch!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")

    // If the below statement prints `nil` this is what's causing the crash
    print(NumSwitch)

    NumSwitch.setOn(isOn, animated: false)
}


@IBAction func SaveSwitchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "switchState")
}
```

The error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)` usually means that you're trying to force unwrap an optional value. The only thing that could be causing that in your code is if `NumSwitch` is `nil`.

I'd also suggest not naming your properties with capital letters, as this can be misleading. Capitalised names are usually used to indicate declared types/classes/structs etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, when I used your code `override let isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState")
        
        NumSwitch.setOn(isOn, animated: false)` I still got the `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)` error just this time highlighting the `NumSwitch.setOn(isOn, animated: false)` line

Comment: It seems like your `NumSwitch` outlet isn't hooked up properly, did you create the outlet through the storyboard using the assistance editor?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by assistance editor but I can tell you how I hooked up my switch. I control clicked it in the storyboard and then connected the blue line to my ViewController.swift file.

Comment: Yeah, that's the correct way to do that. It seems like something has gone wrong though, if `NumSwitch` is == `nil` then you will get a crash and see the error you're getting. Try deleting the `@IBOutlet weak var NumSwitch: UISwitch!` line and add it back in again, see if that helps. Also when the dialog box appears set the storage as `strong` not `weak`. `weak` outlets can sometimes deallocate from memory which could also cause it to be `nil`

Comment: I reconnected `@IBOutlet weak var NumSwitch: UISwitch!` this time changing it to `@IBOutlet var NumSwitch: UISwitch!`as you suggested but when I ran the program I still got an error

Comment: Okay, sometimes Xcode can save old referencing outlets and this can cause crashes, if you select your view controller in the storyboard and select the "Show Connections Inspector" on the righthand slide out panel (This is the last icon with the arrow) check to see that there aren't any outlets saved there that aren't supposed to be there. If there are ones that shouldn't be there then you can tap the x to delete them. Make sure you don't delete the `view` outlet though.

Comment: Is that the black window which you can also control click (on the view controller icon) to find?

Comment: Thanks for the photo, I found the window but could not see any yellow error signs or anything unexpected

Comment: Also I just noticed that you used a `print()` command which when I tried before created the same error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION)

Comment: Hmm, the crash is being caused by that outlet returning nil, something must be incorrect with that outlet, the code you have in place for setting the state is correct and should work. I'm not sure how to help you further without seeing the storyboard/project files. I'd triple check everything with that view controller, perhaps erase it all and build it again if you haven't built a lot of it yet.

Comment: If you want my entire code I am perfectly happy to give it to you though since I am very new to stackoverflow I would not be entirely sure how to do that. And it would quite a lot of work on your part so I would not be offended if you don't want to.

Comment: The main problem with erasing it all and rebuilding it is that I have completed all the main functions of the app and I (probably idiotically) left this problem to the end hoping it would be a relatively easy fix. I think there may be a problem in the fact that I am connecting two UIViewcontrollers to one ViewController Class file. I could (relatively easily) change this but I do not know how to get information from one file to the other.

Comment: So do you have 2 UIViewControllers on your storyboard that both use the same class/code that you posted above? This is most likely the cause of your problem as the outlets will be referencing different UISwitch objects. Instead of having two view controllers can't you just segue to the same view controller from different points within the app? Was there a reason to have two different controllers?

Comment: I do have 2 UIViewControllers on my storyboard that both use the same class code but in my entire I have only 1 UISwitch and so it could not be referencing any other switch. My two UIViewControllers are used for different purposes. The first is the main purpose of the app, the second is supposed to be the settings page with switches on it (though only one switch at the moment).

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is what's causing your problem, I imagine Xcode is getting its wires crossed with the outlets. As a general rule I would create a new UIViewController class for each UIViewController on your storyboard. If some of the logic contained in these view controllers is shared you can consider creating a superclass that both of them inherit from, but as you've said previously you're fairly new to this so creating a separate class for each UIViewController is probably the best way to go for now.

Comment: Ok... do you have any good video links of any kind to show me how to do this? Thanks for all the help you've given me Ill definitely try to redo the viewcontrollers (I actually have about 4 connected to one file (though 3 of them don't have any inputs)) Since it will be only boolean inputs that I will want to share between two view controllers is there an easier way than a super class? Thanks again